# Is it possible to write this type of query with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table like this.

Product table

- product_id
- product_type
- product_price

Select all (product price between 100 and 1000 if product type is "abc") and (product price between 2500 and 5000 if product type is "def") {If the product type has any other name without "abc" or "def" those also should be selected.. }

Is it possible to write this type of query with MySQL? If then how ? I tried but there is no success.

Comment: One simple approach could be to split this into two queries and use `UNION` afterwards.

Comment: _I tried but there is no success._ -> Please show some of your queries

Comment: Yes. Perfectly possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE 
    (product_type = "abc" AND (product_price >= 100 AND product_price <= 1000))
    OR (product_type = "def" AND (product_price >= 2500 AND product_price <= 5000))
    OR product_type NOT IN ("abc", "def")
```